# GE PFSS6PKXESS Icemaker Not Making Ice

Tags: ice-maker

Got a GE PFSS6PKXESS fridge, french door with bottom freezer.  Icemaker stopped making ice.  Dispenser works, but with no ice, it just cranks away and obvs nothing comes out.  Water dispenser dispenses cold water.  The icemaker itself was replaced a couple years ago (they apparently tend to strip the gears inside), so I'm reasonably confident it works mechanically.  The cold air inlet at the icemaker blows cold air.  No change with new filter.  I removed the icemaker to inspect and the ice tray was dry, so I'm thinking it's not getting water.

Water routing appears to be from the wall, into the top right (rear) of the cabinet where the filter is, presumably through the filter, then out top right of the cabinet outside down to the water inlet at the lower left (rear).  From the water inlet there's a long black hose going straight up outside to the top left of the cabinet, where the icemaker is (I *assume* that's the supply for the icemaker).  From the water inlet there is another short hose that goes up inside the bottom of the freezer cabinet—I don't *know* what that one is, but suspect it goes to the water tank for the door dispenser.  Unfortunately, the online parts diagrams are light on depictions of hose routing.

What I don't know is how the fridge doles out the water to the icemaker.  Is the problem likely to be the water inlet, or some control board, or the icemaker itself (again)?